# Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-analytics-1.0.0-runtime

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSUbE.png)

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-analytics-1.0.0-runtime (io.bidmachine:analytics:1.0.0) and jetified-mediationsdk-7.6.0-runtime (com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.6.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequestKt found in modules work-runtime-2.8.1-runtime (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1) and work-runtime-ktx-2.7.0-runtime (androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0)
> Duplicate class androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequestKt found in modules work-runtime-2.8.1-runtime (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1) and work-runtime-ktx-2.7.0-runtime (androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.